# Deploying war file in Payara 4 with Ejb components dependencies

Tags: annotations, ejb, war, payara

Can we deploy a war file in Payara 4 having @Ejb annotated components in it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Any annotations that are part of any Java EE 7 specification are processed by Payara and should work.

Comment: okay. What in case of custom annotations been used in the Project ?

Comment: Annotations not part of Java EE APIs, MicroProfile APIs or Payara API will be simply ignored. So, custom annotations, if they are not derived from the supported APIs, will be ignored by Payara Server and should not interfere with the deployment. If you have a problem with deploying your application, please raise another question with more details.